# Unable to setup mysql with Django on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, virtualenv

I installed the recent version of MySQL for my mac (macOS 12(ARM, 64-bit), DMG Archive) and created a database called storefront. I'm working in a pipenv virtual environment and install mysqlclient. I've also updated my DATABASES settings to point to my new database in my settings.py file.
[DB Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4LdO.png). But whenever I try to run the server I get an error. `NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined` Also at the top, `(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')` I thought by installing the ARM version I wouldn't deal with this error. I wonder if it's pointing to the wrong file within my env despite adding the PATH to my .zshrc info. Is there a special way to point to the correct mysql or am I setting things up incorrectly? Here's my error message "

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/Documents/Scripts/Django/storefront/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/Documents/Scripts/Django/storefront/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 141, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 369, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 235, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 208, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/a0c08w6/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront-A2x2yZd3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Error tell you, you have mysql macOs build for x86_64, but you should set up build for 'arm64e'.

here you can find both version for macOs:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

I install mySql many times on macos... and now i have mariaDb
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-on-macos-using-homebrew/
For me it was easier to install